# LogicApps outlook.com connector GetEmails trigger - get oldest emails

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get oldest emails from outlook.com mailbox within LogicApp. I have done number of test and seems like both triggers available `GetEmails` and `GetEmails(2)` always start from the newest messages.

My use case:
Emails after processing are moved to `Processed` folder and shall be stored there for a month. So am looking for a way to get list of x number of oldest emails to check whether they are older than 30 days, and delete them if condition is met.

With the current functionality, I would have to get all the emails from the folder, what might be few thousands within 30 days time slot. This creates an unnecessary workload on the outlook.com but also within LogicApp. Additionally I am afraid I can reach thresholds for this connector.

Is there a way to get x number of emails starting from the oldest ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get top X oldest emails in a folder of outlook mailbox, you can use Microsoft Graph API by Http action in Logic App to get emails you want directly.

For instance , if I want to get top 5 oldest emails in `Processed` folder, use the API below :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<username>/mailFolders('Processed')/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime&$top=5
```

In logic App :

[image]

I have tested on my side and it works perfectly for me.

Details of Microsoft Graph outlook mail API [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) .

And [how to customize responses from API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

And [Auth for Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0).

If you have any further concerns, pls feel free to let me know.

Comment: An interesting approach, which might be applied to wider range of cases. I have found another solution specific to outlook.com connector. Within `GetEmails` action parameter `SearchQuerry` accepts `received<FomattedDate`, where `FormattedDate` has to be an expression formatted as 'MM/dd/yy'. With support from Azure team.